# Indexing strategy for MongoDB to prevent trashed records being indexed

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In one of my collection I am having deleted records marked as trash: true,  Now can I index only records not marked as trash. What indexing strategy should I use here.

```
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ad5eb0b9590e413debd81d6"),
  "voucher" : ObjectId("5a731de8ffd6f75b1471742f"),
  "brand" : ObjectId("58e3b1e1b473f74462d6c9b2"),
  "code" : "6DZQ34KD",
  "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2018-04-17T12:39:39.287Z"),
  "owner" : ObjectId("5ac3460b8dd26664ab57cb66"),
  "isInWishlist" : true,
  "expiryDate" : ISODate("2018-04-30T20:59:59.000Z"),
  "isUsed" : false,
  "trash" : true,
  "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-17T12:39:39.800Z"),
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-17T12:39:39.288Z"),
  "__v" : 0
 }
```

Comment: No you cannot. The most you can ever do is with "sparse" or "partial" where a property is not present in a document that it would also be excluded from the index. i.e If the index is on `"trash"` and documents that are "not trash" ( don't have the property at all ) would not be in that index. But if you have an index on `"code"`, then you cannot say "don't include if `"trash"` is `true`. If you want things **gone**, then remove them from the collection and store somewhere else if you need a copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [partial index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial).

E.g. to index documents with `"trash": false` by `brand`:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   { brand: 1},
   { partialFilterExpression: { trash: false } }
)
```

Please note the documents without `trash` field will also be excluded from the index.